# Can't create table `issue`.`section_comments

Tags: php, laravel

Can't create table `issue`.`section_comments` on migration

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `issue`.`section_comments` 
(errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") 
(SQL: alter table `section_comments` add constraint `section_comments_parent_id_foreign` foreign key (`parent_id`) references `petition_comments` (`id`))
```

migration

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('section_comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('petition_id')->constrained();
            $table->text('comment_text');
            $table->foreignId('parent_id')->nullable()->references('id')->on('section_comments');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: What does the schema for `petition_comments` look like?

Comment: that's was a mistake I it's section_comments but I'm still getting the error

Comment: This looks like something is generating SQL for MySQL (using backticks to quote table and column names), but running it on MS SQL Server (which uses either square brackets or double-quotes for that). I don't know Laravel in particular, but maybe you have some configuration wrong somewhere?

Comment: Kindly show your petition migration.

Comment: @INSIDECAMPUSTV Ok, but its impossible for us to tell if you don't show us the current error, the current code - the schema for BOTH tables. Without the full information, we can't really help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you should change it to like this;

```
$table->foreignId('petition_id')->constrained(‘petitions’);
```

Delete this line;

```
$table->foreignId('parent_id')->nullable()->references('id')->on('section_comments');
```

Add a new migration file or add below code after Schema::create;

```
Schema::table('section_comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->foreignId('parent_id')->nullable()->constrained('section_comments’);
});
```